# Expression.Call with IEnumerable<string> parameter

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, expression-trees

I want to implement this simple code using expression tree.

```
var strs = new List<string>(){"m", "k", "l"};
var result = string.Concat(strs); // result = "mkl"
```

My code looks like:

```
var exps = new List<Expression>
{ 
   Expression.Constant("m"), 
   Expression.Constant("k"), 
   Expression.Constant("l") 
};
var concat = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<string>) });
Expression.Call(concat, exps);
```

But there is *exception*: `Wrong number of type arguments passed to method`

What's wrong and how I can do it?

---

When I use:

```
var concat = typeof (string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] {typeof (string), typeof (string)});
Expression.Call(concat, exps[0], exps[1]);
```

Comment: Your exps var is List of Expressions, while it looks lite concat var expect to get List of strings

Comment: Kram, question updated

Comment: Add Type after you new  : var concat = typeof (string).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] {typeof (string), typeof (string)});
Expression.Call(concat, exps[0], exps[1]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Concat` here takes an argument of `IEnumerable<string>` rather than `three` string arguments, so you should use an expression that is of type `IEnumerable<string>` for the argument e.g.

```
var argExpression = Expression.Constant(new List<string>() { "m", "k", "l" });

var concat = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<string>) });
Expression.Call(concat, argExpression);
```

To construct an `IEnumerable<string>` from expressions to pass as a single argument then you could construct an array:

```
var exps = new List<Expression>
{ 
    Expression.Constant("m"), 
    Expression.Constant("k"), 
    Expression.Constant("l") 
};

var concat = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<string>) });
var argExpr = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), exps);
Expression.Call(concat, argExpr);
```

Comment: There is one problem: What if one of my strings is variable?
I will update my question in 5 secs.

Comment: @Chepene add it into the list e.g. `new List<string>() { "m", "k", "l", someVariable }`

Comment: it will compile with value of someVariable, but not with variable.. If I will call function with another parameters, it will compile one more time?

Comment: @Chepene Ah I didn't realise it would be an `Expression` variable, check the edit